# get the data of latest upload from created_at column

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Below is my function in my controller.

```
public function getUserTimesheet($userId)
{
    $user = User::find($userId);
    if($user) {

        $userTimesheets = $user->userTimesheets->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->month());

        return response()->json([
            "status" => true,
            "data" => [
                "user-timesheets" => $userTimesheets
            ]
        ], 200);
    }

    return response()->json([
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "User not found"
    ], 401);
}
```

I did create model for the same function.

Multiple timesheets will be uploaded for the same user but I want to return the data of latest upload. I have crated_at column in my respective database and want to compare it to get latest timesheet information by comparing months.

I am getting an error of call to a member function where() on null.
Am new to laravel and creating APIs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the userTimesheets relationship on the particular user is null. Check whether the user has any timesheets, if they have any check how the userTimesheets relationship is defined.